# Using setuptools, can I make my Python package depend-on/install a non-Python utility/executable?

Tags: python-3.x, packaging, setuptools, pypi

I'm trying to write a Python utility that is a thin wrapper around an existing command line program (wmctrl - https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo/wmctrl/).

I'd like to make my program available on PyPI to share my work later on.  But as wmctrl has the core functionality, my code depends heavily on it being installed.

**Is there a way to configure setuptools to depend on a non-Python/non-setuptools dependency like wmctrl?**  I'd like setuptools to fail the install if the binary isn't there.  (Ideally, I'd like setuptools to install it, but that seems less likely...).

Python Packaging/setuptools seems to be really geared towards working with other Python-packaged dependencies (PyPI packages, setuptools-based VCS repos, etc.).  I haven't been able to find anything online about configuring it to depend on other third-party executables.

Thanks to anyone who can offer some guidance/help here.

Comment: Depending is rather simple. You can just check in your `setup.py` if a certain tool is present and raise an error if it is not. Installing non-pythonic dependencies in setup.py is tricky. In fact I have never seen this in a larger project.